# using "new this.GetType()" in a base class to instantiate a derived class

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism

I have a base class A and classes B and C are derived from it. A is an abstract class, and all three classes have a constructor that takes 2 arguments. Is it possible to make a method in the base class A like this:

```
A* clone() const
{
    return new this.GetType(value1, value2);
}
```

and if the current object whose clone()-function is being called is for example C, the function will return the pointer to a new object of class type C?

Comment: Is this Managed C++? Our responses have been for standard C++, though tdammers has discussed the Managed portion as well.

Comment: Normal C++, thanks for all the answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like C++.NET (a.k.a. "managed C++") rather than plain (standard) C++. I'm not an expert on this, but my guess (assuming .NET) would be that you'd have to use reflection to instantiate an object of a `System.Type`. The usual steps are:

1. Create or get a suitable `Type` object, e.g. by calling `GetType`.
2. Find a suitable `ConstructorInfo` (`Type.GetConstructors()` IIRC)
3. Call `ConstructorInfo.Invoke()` to create an instance
4. Cast the resulting `System.Object` to the desired type.

In regular C++, you can't do this at all, because the language simply doesn't have reflection, and type information is mostly lost at run time (RTTI can compare and test run-time types of objects, but that's about it). You'll have to implement a new clone method for each derived class; the pattern I usually use looks something like this:

```
class Foobar : public Baz {
  public:
    int extra; // public for demonstration purposes

    // Copy constructor takes care of actual copying
    Foobar(const Foobar& rhs) : Baz(rhs), extra(rhs.extra) { }

    // clone() uses copy constructor to create identical instance.
    // Note that the return type is Baz*, not Foobar*, so that inheritance works
    // as expected.
    virtual Baz* clone() const { return new Foobar(*this); }
};
```

Comment: How would the opposite make any sense at all?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `clone()` a virtual function and override it in class `C`, like so:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual A* clone() const  {  return new A(v1, v2);  }
}

class C : public A
{
public:
    virtual A* clone() const  {  return new C(v1, v2);  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `clone()` virtual and have subclasses B and C implement their own version of `clone()` and return a new instance of themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing particularly wrong with the other answers, but if I was assuming all subclasses of A could be `clone()`ed just by constructing with two parameters, then I'd do it like this:

```
class A
{
  public:
    A* clone() const  { return create(value1, value2); }
  private:
    virtual A* create(Type1 v1, Type2 v2) const { return new A(v1, v2); }
};

class C : public A
{
    virtual C* create(Type1 v1, Type2 v2) const { return new C(v1, v2); }
};
```

If nothing else, this means that `value1` and `value2` don't need to be accessible in class C - they could be private members. If they're non-trivial expressions, they don't need to be repeated in C either.

That's a bit of a dubious assumption, though - more likely you'd want `clone()` to use the derived class's copy constructor, as in tdammers's answer.